# Check added record at selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I add users with random mail address via selenium. email address is unique therefore I create a random mail address like "12345@abc.com". I want to check whether this email address has been saved or not. Hence, I want to search this email address at my user's table (at web driver, not database). How may I keep random email address and use it for search?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `user's table`?

Comment: if u need to use some data between different tests u need some global variable which may be set and get. Depends on your test project architecture

Comment: you can assume my table like this. when 
 I add a user, user information seems at this table. I want to check the user that I added .https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview